# Amazon SES on AWS Educate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to setup SES, but when I try to verify my domain, I get:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::883709497821:assumed-role/vocstartsoft/(user id) is not authorized to perform: ses:VerifyDomainIdentity with an explicit deny (Request ID: 7b688fe8-fabf-4ff0-bc96-c27de1b007e0)
```

I'm also denied ses:ListIdentities and ses:VerifyEmailIdentity.

I know I can't change the IAM configuration to fix this because of the limitations of Educate, and I can't switch roles.

My friend was able to set up SES on Educate but doesn't recall how he did it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Different classrooms can have different permissions. So your friend could be using classroom with more permissions?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Educate intentionally locks-down accounts.

I suggest you contact the AWS Educate team at: [AWS Educate | Contact Us](https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/contact-us/)